s3 bucket policy erroring out
I got an s3 bucket and every time a file is dropped, it will get a tag added. Whenever a tag is added, i want to send an SNS notification. so I created an SNS topic and added myself to email subscription. Next i created an event notification in s3 bucket and modified my bucket policy to add permission to publish SNS notifictaion. Below is the policy statement:
{
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::123456789:role/CdkTestStack-myresource-s3"
            },
            "Action": [
                "sns:Publish"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:sns:us-west-1:987654321:sns-topic-name/*"
            ]
        }

I see errors  as below:
Unsupported action in policy: The action sns:Publish is not supported for the resource-based policy attached to the resource type s3 bucket.
Unsupported resource ARN in policy: The resource ARN is not supported for the resource-based policy attached to the resource type s3 bucket.

Can i get some help on how this can be fixed pls?

The above policy should be added under SNS > Access Policy . An example policy is given with instructions at link . In short, for S3 service to use the SNS topic, the policy to allow it should be added at SNS side. After this set, enable notification at S3 using link
